# Failing to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with AMD Vega 56

Tags: system-installation, graphics, amd-graphics, additional-drivers

I have a DELL Precision T5610 workstation with an Gigabyte AMD Vega 56 graphic card installed running a dual-boot Windows 10 + Linux environment. The graphic card is connected via DisplayPort cable to a DELL 4919UW with 5120x1440 pixels.

The systems runs fine with Windows 10. Fortnite runs in native resolution and peaks at 90 fps.

The Linux should be an Ubuntu 18.04 for programming. I only require 2D HW-accelerated window manager, no 3D, no Vulkan, no fancy ding bits. I just need to be able to use Atom, a web browser and many many terminals in a super fast setup.

I am able to install Ubuntu with the **nomodeset** parameter within grub from the Installer DVD. After a reboot, installing updates the system does not have HW accelerated graphics - it's slow as in 1980s...

nomodeset is added to grub automatically, which seems to disable the amdgpu driver, so all windows are rendered in software and unusable slow.

When removing nodmodeset from grub the system is stuck with a black screen and does not boot into a WM. The only way to boot is to use Recovery mode and select resume. But then again it is slow.

dmesg reports *VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting* and tried to pass amdgpu.dc=0 options in grup. Still no success. Disabled the VGA graphical console in grub - no change.

Installed AMD's drivers, both amdgpu-pro-install and amdgpu-install (for FOSS drivers). Still no success. Either the system does not boot or it's slow. The FOSS drivers only recognize 3440x1200 pixels instead of 5120x1440.

As the workstation runs fine under Windows 10 with Fortnite I think I can rule out all power related issues.

[ADDED]Truncated dmesg after recovery boot:

```
os@oliver-linuxdev:~$ dmesg
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.3.0-40-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-024) (gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)) #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 14:05:59 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.3.0-40.32~18.04.1-generic 5.3.18)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.3.0-40-generic root=UUID=21d530af-4ff0-4b20-8e8f-702206bdaf21 ro recovery nomodeset
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] DMI: Dell Inc. Precision T5610/0WN7Y6, BIOS A18 11/14/2018
[    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
[    0.000000] tsc: Detected 2094.921 MHz processor
[    0.005334] total RAM covered: 32736M
[    0.185968] smpboot: Allowing 24 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[    0.188695] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.3.0-40-generic root=UUID=21d530af-4ff0-4b20-8e8f-702206bdaf21 ro recovery nomodeset
[    0.188782] You have booted with nomodeset. This means your GPU drivers are DISABLED
[    0.188783] Any video related functionality will be severely degraded, and you may not even be able to suspend the system properly
[    0.188784] Unless you actually understand what nomodeset does, you should reboot without enabling it
[    3.396076] hid-generic 0003:17F6:0864.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Unicomp Inc Unicomp R7_2_Apple_10x_Kbrd_v7_37] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6/input0
[    3.398083] input: Unicomp Inc Unicomp R7_2_Apple_10x_Kbrd_v7_37 System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.1/0003:17F6:0864.0003/input/input4
[    3.456052] input: Unicomp Inc Unicomp R7_2_Apple_10x_Kbrd_v7_37 Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-Device [Unicomp Inc Unicomp R7_2_Apple_10x_Kbrd_v7_37] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6/input1
[    3.488035] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2812, bcdDevice= b.e0
[    4.694519] [drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting.
[    4.735944] Adding 15999996k swap on /dev/sda2.  Priority:-2 extents:1
```

[ADDED lspci]

```
os@oliver-linuxdev:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 DMI2 (rev 04)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 1a (rev 04)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 2a (rev 04)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 3a (rev 04)
00:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 VTd/Memory Map/Misc (rev 04)
00:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 IIO RAS (rev 04)
00:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 IOAPIC (rev 04)
00:11.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset PCI Express Virtual Root Port (rev 06)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset MEI Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:16.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset IDE-r Controller (rev 05)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset KT Controller (rev 05)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b6)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset LPC Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset SATA RAID Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset SMBus Host Controller (rev 06)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1470 (rev c3)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1471
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Vega 10 XT [Radeon RX Vega 64] (rev c3)
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device aaf8
07:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720201 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)
7f:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Link 0 (rev 04)
7f:09.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Link 1 (rev 04)
7f:0a.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 0 (rev 04)
7f:0a.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 1 (rev 04)
7f:0a.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 2 (rev 04)
7f:0a.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 3 (rev 04)
7f:0b.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 UBOX Registers (rev 04)
7f:0b.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 UBOX Registers (rev 04)
7f:0c.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
7f:0c.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
7f:0c.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
7f:0d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
7f:0d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
7f:0d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
7f:0e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Home Agent 0 (rev 04)
7f:0e.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Home Agent 0 (rev 04)
7f:0f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address/Thermal Registers (rev 04)
7f:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 RAS Registers (rev 04)
7f:0f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
7f:0f.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
7f:0f.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
7f:0f.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
7f:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 0 (rev 04)
7f:10.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 1 (rev 04)
7f:10.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 0 (rev 04)
7f:10.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 1 (rev 04)
7f:10.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 2 (rev 04)
7f:10.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 3 (rev 04)
7f:10.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 2 (rev 04)
7f:10.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 3 (rev 04)
7f:13.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 R2PCIe (rev 04)
7f:13.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 R2PCIe (rev 04)
7f:13.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Ring Registers (rev 04)
7f:13.5 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Ring Performance Ring Monitoring (rev 04)
7f:16.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 System Address Decoder (rev 04)
7f:16.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Broadcast Registers (rev 04)
7f:16.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Broadcast Registers (rev 04)
80:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 2a (rev 04)
80:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 3a (rev 04)
80:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 VTd/Memory Map/Misc (rev 04)
80:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 IIO RAS (rev 04)
80:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 IOAPIC (rev 04)
ff:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Link 0 (rev 04)
ff:09.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Link 1 (rev 04)
ff:0a.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 0 (rev 04)
ff:0a.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 1 (rev 04)
ff:0a.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 2 (rev 04)
ff:0a.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 3 (rev 04)
ff:0b.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 UBOX Registers (rev 04)
ff:0b.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 UBOX Registers (rev 04)
ff:0c.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
ff:0c.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
ff:0c.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
ff:0d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
ff:0d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
ff:0d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
ff:0e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Home Agent 0 (rev 04)
ff:0e.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Home Agent 0 (rev 04)
ff:0f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address/Thermal Registers (rev 04)
ff:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 RAS Registers (rev 04)
ff:0f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
ff:0f.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
ff:0f.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
ff:0f.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
ff:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 0 (rev 04)
ff:10.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 1 (rev 04)
ff:10.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 0 (rev 04)
ff:10.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 1 (rev 04)
ff:10.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 2 (rev 04)
ff:10.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 3 (rev 04)
ff:10.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 2 (rev 04)
ff:10.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 3 (rev 04)
ff:13.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 R2PCIe (rev 04)
ff:13.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 R2PCIe (rev 04)
ff:13.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Ring Registers (rev 04)
ff:13.5 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Ring Performance Ring Monitoring (rev 04)
ff:16.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 System Address Decoder (rev 04)
ff:16.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Broadcast Registers (rev 04)
ff:16.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Broadcast Registers (rev 04)
```

[ADDED packages]

```
os@oliver-linuxdev:~$ dpkg -l | grep xserver
ii  x11-xserver-utils                          7.7+7build1                                     amd64        X server utilities
ii  xserver-common                             2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4                             all          common files used by various X servers
ii  xserver-xephyr                             2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4                             amd64        nested X server
ii  xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04                2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1           amd64        Xorg X server - core server
ii  xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04                     1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3                         amd64        X.Org X server
ii  xserver-xorg-hwe-amdgpu-video-amdgpu       1:19.0.1-967956                                 amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04           1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3                         amd64        X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04      0.28.1-1~18.04.1                                amd64        X.Org X server -- libinput input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04         1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- Wacom input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04              2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1           amd64        setuid root Xorg server wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04           1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3                         amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04        19.0.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                         amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04           1:19.0.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04         1:0.5.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04         2:2.99.917+git20171229-1ubuntu1~18.04.1         amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04       1:1.0.16-1~18.04.1                              amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04           0.1.5-2build2~18.04.1                           amd64        X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04        1:19.0.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04          1:2.4.0-1~18.04.1                               amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04        1:13.3.0-2build1~18.04.1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver
```

What else can I try to use Ubuntu 18.04 with HW accelerated 2D in 5120x1440?

Thanks, -MN